# How to set child's process std (out / err) as the parent in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, multiprocessing, stdout, stdin

I have a parent process which the user might have set its `std (out / err)` to a specific file (fd).
I want the child process to have the same `std(out / err)` as the parent. (so its output will be to the same file)
I've seen windows supports `GetStdHandle` but couldn't find the equivalent on `Linux`.
I assume I just need to get the `FD` of the parent std pipes and set it using `dup2` for the child process 0, 1 & 2 FD's.

Answer (score 1):

Child processes automatically inherit all file descriptors from parent process so you don't need to do anything.

Comment: Thanks, you reminded me to check and I had CLOSE ON EXEC, this is why the FD's weren't inherited, adding 0, 1 & 2 to the exception list did the job.